# Java Spring - check if user is allowed to view the page or not

Tags: java, spring-mvc

i have some pages that can be viewed only if the user is logged in.
So, in every controller that i want to page that i want to be restricted i put this code:

```
Boolean checkLogin = (Boolean) request.getSession().getAttribute(adminSesName);
if(!checkLogin) return "redirect:/";
```

All my controllers extends a Base Controller, and here i was thinking to put the code that makes the ckeck if a user is logged in or not, but i don't know where to put it.

Do you have some suggestions how to do it?
Thanks!

Comment: since you decided to put this logic. put it inside BaseController inside a method as other controllers gonna extend it you can simply invoke it . Try going through spring security which makes the process easier and where you specify the roles for the user as well .works best with spring MVC application

Comment: please check spring security for cleaner approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use spring security for authentication check. You can start from here [spring security tutorial](https://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-hello-world-annotation-example/)

Answer (score 2):

Spring security would be the best option, he is right. A much easier alternative ( not recommended though) is to implement a filter to do the check for you and you can map it on all url with a wanted structure:
https://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/how-to-register-a-servlet-filter-in-spring-mvc/